# PHP Ratchet can't connect from other device

Tags: php, sockets, ratchet

I'm starting using PhP Ratchet socket. Following the guides I could made a simple chat application and it's working within the same computer. Example, if I open up chrome and firefox, I can interact send and receive messages, ok.

The problem is when I try to use the chat app from another computer, but within the same internet connection, or even when I tried to test it online.

When on lan, the other computers can't connect with the socket and online no one can connect.

By looking around, I found about using '0.0.0.0' or even port 5555 to enable connections from anyone. But even when using this, I can't connect.

How can I solve this? This is my files:

server.php

```
<?php

    use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
    use Ratchet\http\HttpServer;
    use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

    require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Chat()
            )
        ), 2000, '0.0.0.0'
    );

    $server->run();

?>
```

And client js file:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:2000');
```

Comment: In the client have you tried using the server's address instead of `127.0.0.1`, something like `192.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Comment: @codeHeart on the localhost it worked, but how to make it work online?

Comment: Would anyone assist me in doing so the same issue also persists to me also [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52848607/7713811)

Answer (score 1):

`127.0.0.1` will *always* point to the local device, which, on devices other than the socket server, will *not* point to the device that is hosting the socket server. If the device that is running the socket server is not routeable from the internet, you will not be able to connect to the socket from the internet.

You can test from other devices on your LAN by figuring out what your network IP is for the device that is running the server. Then in your client code, connect to *that* IP. It will probably be something close to `192.168.x.x`, e.g. `192.168.1.12` (it could also be in the `10.x.x.x` or `172.16.x.x` address spaces). Then simply use that address to connect from your client script for testing:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.12:2000');
```

You may still run into trouble if, for whatever reason, your network is configured to drop packets on port `2000`. If so, it should be fairly easy for you to change to a different port for both your server and client.

Comment: On the localhost I'm able to test now. But I'm still with problems when using it online. I get this error: `Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.` when I try to send. Or if I wait, it doesn't connect and also return an error `failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: what do you mean by 'online'? did you deploy this to a website located on some server not on your network? my answer above will only work from devices that are on the same network as the socket server

Comment: Yes, I tried to test it online, on a web site. The localhost worked just fine, than I tried it on my website and got those errors. Ps.: Using 127.0.0.1

Comment: remember there's two different sides to any socket- in this case it's the client and the server. in order to connect to the _server_, the client needs to be able to find a route to it. if the client is on some website, it will not be able to route to your chat server on your local network at all (at least, you really really hope so). both will need to be accessible on the internet.

Comment: But then, how can I make it work with the online server as well? Do you know how?

Comment: Yes, you have to deploy the chat server online and get either an IP address or _name_ that you can point your client application to, e.g. `new WebSocket('ws://my.chatserver.com:2000')` or whatever.  You could potentially host them on the same domain as well

Comment: What do you mean by "chat server"? In the localhost I need to run `php bin/server.php`, do I need to do it online?  I didn't found anything about this and the example I used to build this was very simple. Apart from the function to send/receive the msg from the socket, the code on the question is everything I have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105182/discussion-between-jeff-lambert-and-celsomtrindade).

Comment: Would anyone assist me in doing so the same issue also persists to me also [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52848607/7713811)  @JeffLambert